# How to say meeting is about my questions?

Tags: word-request, expressions

I want to ask my supervisor for a meeting. I want to say meeting is about my questions about the approach. Can I use discuss for asking questions?

> I would be grateful for a meeting, at your convenience, to discuss my questions.

Answer (score 2):

I think he would prefer to be forewarned as to the actual subject matter.

How about…

"I would be grateful for a meeting, at your convenience, to discuss the following issues…"

or "...to discuss questions raised by [this known issue]"
or "…to discuss questions I have regarding our approach to…"

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's fine. "Discuss" is the best word to use here...